# Full_picture Parameter for page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token, facebook-debugger

I am using graph API to get access tokken using a reference "pagename?fields=picture" for my facebook page to be used on my website.
This is the function that I am using;

```
    function get_facebook_post_pic_full_url($feed_id)
    {   
        echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $feed_id . "' );</script>";  
        $ursls = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$feed_id.'/?fields=full_picture,picture&access_token="Access Tokken"';
        $fb_act = json_decode(file_get_contents($ursls));
        return $fb_act;
    }


function get_facebook_page_feed($fts_limiter='')
{
    if(!$fts_limiter)
    {
      $fts_limiter = 1;
    }

    $pageid = get_field('facebook_page_id','option');

    //If there's no Access Token then use a default
    $access_token_array = array(
        'sampleaccess tokken'
 'sampleaccess tokken'
 'sampleaccess tokken'
    );

    $access_token = $access_token_array[rand(0, 11)];

    $graph_data = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$pageid.'/posts?fields=id,from,message,story,story_tags,link,source,name,caption,description,type,status_type,object_id,attachments,created_time&access_token='.$access_token.'&limit=1&locale=en_US';

    $fb_activity = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_data));
    return $fb_activity;
}
```

And this is used to fetch and display image and caption and date;

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 no-padding">
<div class="facebook_img">
  <?php
  $fb_feeds = get_facebook_page_feed();

  if(!empty($fb_feeds)):

        $feeds = $fb_feeds->data[0];
        $created_time = $feeds->created_time;
        $link = $feeds->link;
        $feed_id = $feeds->id;

        $full_arr = get_facebook_post_pic_full_url($feed_id);

        $full_picture = $full_arr->full_picture;
        $message = $feeds->message;
        $submessage = substr($message,0,75);

    ?>
    <!--<?php  var_dump($full_arr);?> -->
  <img style="width:405px;height:341px" src="<?php echo $full_picture; ?>" alt="facebook"/>
  <div class="fb_content"> <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $submessage; ?></a>
    <dt><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($created_time)); ?></dt>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The issue is that I am getting this error when I run;  $ursls = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$feed_id.'/?fields=full_picture,picture&access_token="Access Tokken"';

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (full_picture) on node type (Page)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "traceid"
   }
}
```

The code and everything was working fine and it has stopped 2 months ago. Can anyone please tell me why full_picture is nonexisting field? Does that mean that we can not use full_picture parameter for page anymore? Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: According to the error message you tried to request this field for a page, instead of a post.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your reply. I got the issue sorted. I was trying to sort it from 2 months and it is finally resolved. The access tokken that was using was wrong. My feed is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code and everything is working fine and facebook has not changed any parameters that are used in the above post. My access tokken was having some issues, I generated a new one and it started to work now. Thank you!